# How to add point to all points of a polygon or geometry in mysql?

Tags: mysql, geometry, gis, polygon, spatial

I have a polygon @poly and a point @p as:

```
SET @poly = ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))');
SET @p = ST_GeomFromText('Point(1 2)');
```

I want to add @p into @poly to get a new polygon as:

```
Polygon((1 2,1 5,4 5,4 2,1 2))
```

But I couldn't find a solution for this.

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can try to create a new collection and add polygon and point together.

Another one - Use WKB/WKT and parse the points @poly and append @p.

You can read more info here : https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT

Comment: thanks, for the respond. can you also provide a sql sample code, I tried but failed.

Comment: Can you share the sql, You can check  ST Union operation  like this :                  SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))'),
 ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2 3)') ) )

Comment: tried this, but creating a union doesn't add the point's x and y into polygon's x y values.